# Single symbol to multiple identifiers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In the "**Well grounded Rubyist 2nd Edition**", David Black states that (p.239):

> The symbol table is just that: a symbol table. It’s not an object table.  **If you use an identifier for more than one purpose—say, as a local variable and also as a method name—** the corresponding symbol will still only appear once in the symbol table

Then the author goes ahead and gives the following example:

```
>> Symbol.all_symbols.size
=> 3118
>> abc = 1
=> 1
>> Symbol.all_symbols.size
=> 3119
>> def abc; end
=> :abc
>> Symbol.all_symbols.size
=> 3119
```

My question is two-fold:

1. **How is it possible to have the same identifier for more than one purpose**!? - I understand that Ruby knows which one is which based on context but is this enough?
2. The symbol that was created in the example above, **which identifier does it refer to**? The local variable or the method name?

Comment: You also use numbers more than once. You could assign `1` to a variable (`abc = 1`) and use it as an array index (`ary[1]`) without any problems. Now, does `1` refer to the variable value or to the array index? Both, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

Let's untangle this one by one.

> - "How is it possible to have the same identifier for more than one purpose!?"
> - "The symbol that was created, which identifier does it refer to?"

Let me first start with code that might look more familiar.

Obviously we can use the same string `str` to store two objects in two hashes

```
str = "max"
people[str] = Person.new
statistics[str] = 42
```

Now your example code does exactly the same

```
# pseudo-code
sym = :abc  
locals[sym] = 1
methods[sym] = Method.new(...)
```

Internally Ruby represents everything using hashes

- there is a hash with all classes
- for each class there is a hash with all methods
- for each instance there is a hash with all instance variables
- for each method activation there is a hash with all local variables
- et cetera
- …

Symbols are used as keys into those hashes, and as such the same symbol can be used many times to map to many things in many hashes. Just the same way the code in your Rails app may use the same string as key in many different hash objects.

Now symbols are somewhat special. There is one and only one instance for `:abc` and Ruby uses a hash, yet another hash — the so-called symbol table — to map all symbols to an internal magic number. And then these magic numbers are used internally to refer to the symbol. I guess that is why the author of the book wrote "the symbols table is not an object table."

Mapping a string `"abc"` to these internal numbers is called "interning" and hence symbols are sometimes referred to as interned strings.

Fun fact, you can lookup these magic numbers yourself with `:symbol.object_id` and even infer from the order of numbers which symbols have been created first.

Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: Thanks. That make TONS of sense!

Answer (score 1):

I have not read the book, but the first two sentences seem to refer to the same questions you ask:

> The symbol table is just that: a symbol table. It’s not an object table.

In other words - symbols can be names for identifiers, but they are not identifiers, nor do they have 1:1 mapping with identifiers directly (without context).

`foo` is an identifier. `:foo` is just the name of that identifier.

---

1. *How is it possible to have two people named John?* It's just a name, not an id.
2. *Which person does the name John refer to?* Depends on the context. In this case - the variable.

---

I can go into further details on how the actual resolution happens in the language if this question wasn't conceptual in nature.